# what are some ways a floating point can overflow?

Tags: floating-point

From what I can tell, one way is that the exponent may be too large to be represented. Is it also the case that overflow can happen in the sign bit and mantissa/fraction as well?

Comment: The sign can only be +/-.  If the fraction "overflows" then the exponent is just incremented (and then the exponent eventually overflows).  But of course, there is also exponent *underflow* and NaN (mainly due to divide by zero).  And there's loss of precision.

Comment: @HotLicks Each of the basic operations can produce a NaN: ∞ - ∞, ∞ + (-∞), 0 * ∞. Division of zero by zero can be called the “main” cause of NaN in that it is the only one that requires only finite arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The term “overflow” refers **only** to results of excessive magnitude, per IEEE 754-2008 7.4: “The overflow exception shall be signaled if and only if the destination format’s largest finite number is exceeded in magnitude by what would have been the rounded floating-point result (see 4) were the exponent range unbounded.”

Your question appears to show interest in other exceptions. That is, other situations in which the bounds of floating-point arithmetic are reached and a mathematically ideal result cannot be delivered. IEEE 754 specifies exceptions for invalid operation, division by zero, overflow, underflow, and inexactness.

An invalid operation occurs for:

- Any general-computational or signaling-computational operation on a signaling NaN. (This excludes operations like asking “Is this a NaN?”, for which a signaling NaN could be a normal operand, not an exceptional operand.)
- Multiplying an infinity by a zero (directly or in a fused multiply-add).
- Adding infinities with opposite signs or subtracting infinities with the same sign.
- Dividing a zero by a zero or an infinity by an infinity.
- Remainder when the divisor is zero or the numerator is infinite.
- Square root of a value less than zero.
- A “quantize” operation when the result does not fit in the destination format or when one operand is finite and the other is infinite.
- Conversion of a floating-point number to an integer when the result is too large or is NaN or an infinity.
- Comparison with a NaN using an operation that is specifically designated to signal if given a NaN.
- Some integer-logarithm functions when the operand is a NaN, infinity, or zero.

Division by zero occurs for:

- An exact infinite result occurs for finite operands (e.g., 3/0 but not infinity/1).

Underflow occurs for:

- A tiny result (in the subnormal interval) is detected. This is implementation dependent: The result used for the underflow criterion may be the exact mathematical result or may have its significand rounded.

(Although the underflow exception technically occurs when a tiny non-zero result is detected, it is ignored and has no observable effect if default exception handling is enabled and the final rounded result is exact.)

Inexact occurs for:

- The rounded result of an operation is different from the exact mathematical result.

Note that although exceptions may occur, the language you are programming in may ignore them and not cause them to generate traps (exceptional changes of program control). There may or may not be provision in the language or its implementation for enabling traps or for examining the status flags that indicate whether exceptions have occurred.